# Wifi connections disappers with WIN 7

Tags: windows-7

I bought couple of new Dell Latitude E5420 laptops and Dell E-port Simple replicators. Laptops have Win 7 64 bit.

**Problem:** Wifi connection disappears, when I put laptop in E-port. Without replicator wifi connection works fine. Other hardware (extra monitor, keyboard and mouse) work without problems with the replicator. 
Since I bought multiple laptops and replicators I tried to combine them differently, but the problem stays every combinations. Puting laptop in port replicator wifi connection disappers: all wifi networks are shown as usual, but it does not connect: shows "unidentified network" and "no internet access". I tried reinstall drivers, but it didnt help.

I have other Dell laptops (d830, d430 ja E6400) in the same wifi network connected to  port replications and they have connections, but they all have WIN XP.

Can You help me find a solution to that problem?

Comment: Does your port replicator have a hard-wired network connection?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in BIOS, on "Wireless Radio Control", there is now the possibility to stop the WiFi connection when a LAN connection (or other) is detected.

When you disconnect from the LAN, WiFi is enabled agagin.